# A set is closed in Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, projective-space, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

This is a statement in Harris A first course of AG's Thm 3.12.

Let $X$ be a subvariety of $Y\times P^2$ where $Y$ is a variety of $A^n$ and $P^2$ is 2 dimensional projective space. Choose any $p\in P^2$ such that $X\cap(Y\times\{p\})\neq\phi$. Then $V=\{q\in Y\vert (q,p)\not\in X\}$ is closed.

I was trying to see $V$ being closed. I tried $Y-V=\{q\in Y\vert (q,p)\in X\}=X\cap(Y\times \{q\})$ which should be closed in $Y$ as I can fix the generator's $P^2$ variable at p which should yield a polynomial vanishing exactly on $Y-V$. I think I am wrong here as I did not get $V$ being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have it with me, but I think this must be a typo.  Consider $X \subset \mathbb{A}^3\times \mathbb{P}^2$ given by $ax + by + cz = 0$ ( where $x,y,z$ are homogeneous coordinates for $\mathbb{P}^2$ ).  Points on this variety $(p,q)$ are points where $p$ is a point on the plane perpendicular to the line through the origin corresponding to $q$.  The set you described $V$ then is $\mathbb{A}^3$ minus a plane, which is clearly not closed.

If you replace the $\notin$ with $\in$, then $V$ is closed by the main theorem of elimination theory ( it's a projection to $Y$ of a closed fiber over a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ )

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt. I think that, in fact, we should have prove $V=\{q\in Y; (q,p)\in X \}$ is closed in Y. This makes sense at the proof: we consider $X=X_1\cup X_2$, where $X_1=X\cap [Y\times \{p\}]$ and $X_2=X\cap[Y\times (\mathbb{P}^2-\{p\})]$. Then $\bar{X}=\bar{X_1}\cup \bar{X_2}$.
As $X$ is closed at $Y\times \mathbb{P}^2$, $X_2$ is closed at $Y\times (\mathbb{P}^2-\{p\})$, and by the previous observation of the book, $\bar{X_2}$ is closed at $U=Y-V$.
About $X_1$, we have exactly $\bar{X_1}=V$. But $X_1=V\times \{q\}$ is closed at $Y\times \{p\}$, what induces $V$ closed at $Y$. Therefore $\bar{X}$ is closed at $Y$.